# Refresh my Account on Finish Button of my Flow

Tags: visualforce, visual-workflow, finishlocation

I embedded my flow into a visualforce page and included the command "finishlocation". Using another visualforcepage and an extension I am only able to close the Flow Window. I would rather like to close and refresh my account detail page. The account page looks like follows: [image]

My visualforce page with the embedded flow looks as follows:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" tabStyle="Account" extensions="CustomAccountController">

    <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around--medium">


    <flow:interview name="newGeschenk" finishLocation="{!Account.Id}">

       <apex:param name="AccountId" value="{!Account.Id}"/>

    </flow:interview>

    </div>
```

My extension looks like follows:

```
public class CustomAccountController {

public CustomAccountController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
}
//Der Controller ruft die Visualforce page "closeFlow" auf 
public PageReference getCloseWindow(){
    return new PageReference('/apex/closeFlow');
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a visualforce page without an extension should work:

```
<apex:page showHeader="true" sidebar="true" standardcontroller="Account">
    <flow:interview name="newGeschenk" finishLocation="/{!Account.Id}">
        <apex:param name="AccountId" value="{!Account.Id}"/>
    </flow:interview>
</apex:page>
```